# read and publish permission in facebook sdk 3.0 iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

In the last SDK, read and publish permissions are separated. So, in my code, whenever the users logs in I am using this code:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
```

I have seen in the facebook developer that when I want to publish, I should ask for publish permissions like this:

```
// can include any of the "publish" or "manage" permissions
NSArray *permissions = 
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil];

[[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                           defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
         /* handle success + failure in block */
         }];
```

Since this is my first app that I am using facebook integration, I want to ask a couple of things:

1) Can these sessions be open at the same time? I will ask for the publish permissions only when the user wants to publish, but should I do something else with the other session? Like close it first, and reopen it later or I should not worry about?

2) If I have a postToFriends button for example, my pseudocode for making it work would be like this, right?

```
- (IBAction)postToFriendaction:(id)sender {
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        /* code from the above for enabling publish permissions*/

    }
```

or I should change !FBSession.activeSession.isOpen to something else, because no the user is logged in with read permission only, he never enters the if clause. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The two sessions you refer to are actually the same session (it's the "active" session that's statically available after a call to openActiveSession... is called). So you don't need to do anything with the other session.
2. You should have a look at either the Scrumptious or Hello Facebook sample apps that ship with the SDK. They both give examples on how to post (while asking for publish permissions).